# How to use an lwc oss web component in a vue project for example?

Tags: lwc-oss

I would like to import this lwc oss component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lwc-clock-utils in a vue project. May someone help me pointing how to properly import the package?

Comment: why do you intend on mixing both? additionally, this lib is basically a stopwatch component, why not build your own with Vue?

Comment: I would like to create web components with LWC and use it in any project, I already have a project in vue that I would like to replace all components for those new ones. I tried to add this one as an example, But I couldn't get it.

Comment: then why not just create an lwc-oss project, and ditch Vue?

Comment: 'cause I would to like to do it gradually. I'll create every base component and replace. It will take some time, I would like that those components in lwc oss can be imported by any project. For example I don't want to use vue button, I would like to  use my lwc button instead in my vue project. I'm looking for this.

Comment: i'm still not sure I understand why you are so keen on mixing frameworks (specially, migrating from vuejs components to lwc-oss components). Vuejs has a much larger community, widespread components and a more mature framework. (not that I have the answer on how to do it, just curious as to WHY you are doing this)

Comment: @RenathoAzevedo, were you able to use the lwc component inside a vue project?